# Modifying a MutableStateFlow List in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a MutableStateFlow `List<>` in my ViewModel:

```
private var _spaces = MutableStateFlow<List<Space>>(listOf())
val spaces: MutableStateFlow<List<Space>> get() = _spaces
```

and I'm updating an item in the list like so:

```
    val existingSpaceIndex: Int = _spaces.value.indexOfFirst { it.id == document.id }

    if (existingSpaceIndex != -1) {
        var modified_spaces = _spaces.value.toMutableList()

        modified_spaces.removeAt(existingSpaceIndex)

        _spaces.value = modified_spaces
    }
```

However, I'm going to be updating it more than once-a-while from multiple methods, and I think if I keep removing the index and re-adding it, I might come across a bug where at times the item doesn't exist when I'm trying to update it.

I tried to do `_spaces.value.removeAt(existingSpaceIndex)` but I get the error:

`Unresolved reference: removeAt`

And I *think* it's because it doesn't see it as a mutable list? But I've declared it as `MutableStateFlow` so not sure how I can just modify the actual list without having to create a temporary one.

How can I fix my declaration so that I can edit items, remove items and mutate the original list I've declared?

Answer (score 1):

You need `MutableStateFlow<MutableList<T>>`. But in this case, your updates to the MutableList will not trigger the flow.

But your problem is parallel conflicts. In that case using MutableList won't solve your problem. You need to solve it with locks or by limiting the number of threads used by the coroutines.